# Where should I set state if I can't do it in my render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am a complete react beginner, and I recently discovered that setting state in my render function is a big no-no because it leads to endless recursion. However, I want to set up a listener for my firebase server that updates the state whenever there's a change to one of my firebase documents. Is there a react function that runs asynchronously to render where I can do these state changes? I tried componentDidUpdate() but it only seems to run once on the initial render.

Comment: Your listener should probably go in `componentDidMount()`, but without you sharing code there's really nothing more that anyone can say to help.

Comment: And you could use useState and go with functional react.

Comment: Are you using this library? https://react-firebase-js.com/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already know one needs to use this.setState method in order to change a value on the page.

in the constructor we need to define this.state object and then whenever someevent happens this value should only be updated with this.setState method as we bind those events to make the change.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }


 this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: In that case you will need to call your fetching method periodically. You should call this method from componentDidMount and then periodically it will be called. Fetch or Axios you may use. Here is a good blog. https://blog.logrocket.com/patterns-for-data-fetching-in-react-981ced7e5c56/